# Replacing fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to have a program that on start displays login screen but the user can click a text that directs them to sign up screen. I'm having trouble replacing the fragment on screen when clicked the text.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager;
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
Fragment fragmentS;
Fragment fragmentL;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.setReorderingAllowed(true);
    fragmentL = new FragmentLogin();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mainLoginOutLayout,fragmentL);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

that is my `onCreate()` method and this is the function that gets called when user clicks the `sign in` text:

```
public void changeToSignUp(View v){
    fragmentS = new FragmentSignUp();
    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.setReorderingAllowed(true);
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mainLoginOutLayout,fragmentS, null);
    fragmentTransaction.commitNow();
    System.out.println("############################################### \n CHANGEDD \n ##########");

}
```

[it runs the code, but doesn't change the view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccIzL.png)

What is the problem?

Comment: Can you post your XML layout for `activity_main`?

Comment: Also check both your fragments, whether, accidentally, you have mentioned same layout to both the Fragments class. Post your code or a link to your Git repo for us to dig deeper please.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check below things -

1. `R.id.mainLoginOutLayout` means `mainLoginOutLayout` is the id of `activity_main`
2. `android:onClick="changeToSignUp"` added inside right TextView in right layout.
3. Also the two different layouts used for `FragmentSignUp` and `FragmentLogin` are different.
4. Also check `onStart()` method in `FragmentSignUp`  , is there any logic which return you in `FragmentLogin` .

Your code executing and working perfectly .